# ActiveRecord - Associations 2 level down are not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.1

I have the following models

```rb
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :votes, through: :options

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
end
```

When I try to create a new vote for an option, and then try to save the post, it will not be shown:

```rb
@poll = Poll.first
@poll.options.first.votes.length # returns 3
@poll.options.first.votes.new
@poll.options.first.votes.length # returns 4
@poll.save # returns true
@poll.votes.length # returns 3.... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Seems like even though I am saving the `poll`, the associations 2 levels down are not being saved.

I have also tried to solve it like this:

```
@poll.votes.new(option: @poll.options.first)
@poll.save
```

But this gives me the following error:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'Poll#votes' because the source reflection class 'Vote' is associated to 'Option' via :has_many.
>   from /home/dbugger/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/through_association.rb:94:in `ensure_mutable'

Comment: `poll.save` is not saving the `vote` because it it doesn't even know how to and the option didn't change so it is not saving either. This process just seems strange to begin with. Generally `has_X :through` is just a convenience query method and I generally try to avoid them anyway so I don't feel like I can do things I shouldn't. If I wanted to know the `votes` for a `Poll` instance,  I would use `def votes; Vote.where(option_id: options); end`

Comment: All that being said `new` just creates a `new` one without association. What your are looking for is `options.first.votes.build` this will associated the `option` to the `vote`. In either case I would never recommend trying to save the `vote` from the `poll`.

Comment: Which way would you recommend me to create votes, given a certain array of "option ids"?

Comment: Depends on how you want to handle a failure and what a vote looks like if a vote is just `id, option_id` then I would go with `Votes.create(option_ids.map {|id| {option_id: id})` the poll has nothing to do with this since the option belongs to the poll the association remains intact.

Comment: But this could lead to a in-between state, if it fails in the middle of the operation. Should I use transactions?